# What's the best way to do this in Python?

Tags: python, list, sorting, collections

I have a list of objects where each of them have `start` and `end` properties like:

```
Item 0:
Start: 1
End: 12

Item 1:
Start: 6
End: 3

Item 2:
Start: 12
End: 6
```

I want to order them so that each item's `start` and `end` matches with the one that comes before and after itself, in the new list.

So in this example, it would be:

```
[Item 0] [Item 2] [Item 1]
[1   12] [12   6] [6    3]
```

It doesn't matter if the whole list was reversed.

Also there are 2 unrelated lists like above mixed in so I have to form 2 new lists that will have the proper order as shown above.

I am just gonna start implementing it "brute-force" so doing a lot of queries to create these lists but I wanted to ask if someone might have a more elegant way to solve this. I am not sure how common this sort of problem but I remember seeing this before, so maybe there are patterns to deal with this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there are perfect match ups for start/end for each start and end:

```
items_by_start = dict((i.start, i) for i in your_items)

ordered_items = [your_items[0]]
for _ in xrange(len(your_items)-1):
    ordered_items.append(items_by_start[ordered_items[-1].end])
```

Comment: Also assuming there are no duplicate `start`s.

Comment: Thanks alot, I will give this a try. I assume this won't care for 2 independent lists being in the same group, right?

Comment: @JoanVenge If you have two separate lists, you'll run into issues with the number of loop repetitions; you'd have to use slightly more complex logic for that.

Comment: Thanks Amber, your logic is still very useful had good assumptions that I am using.

Answer (score 1):

Ordering the elements suggests no duplicate items. However, with duplicate `start`s or `end`s you'd have to be more careful (and more than one solution might be possible). The problem would be equal to finding [Eulerian paths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path) in [connected components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_%28graph_theory%29) of an undirected graph, which can be obtained by treating each (`start`, `end`) pair as a graph edge.

There are more than enough examples of how it can be implemented in Python on the web. Bear in mind, that it can be done easily in O(m) time, where m is the number of edges.

Also, an Euclidean path exists if and only if every vertex has an even degree. It still holds if you have many components in your graph.

Comment: Thanks, my list have no duplicates, basically each item is guaranteed to have unique start and end. But I also found that some start and end values might be reversed.